# tnsping command not working on linux server reboot in /etc/init.d script

Tags: linux, oracle

We need to call 'tnsping' command  on linux server reboot in one of our /etc/init.d script to make sure that oracle service is running on another server. We are getting 'TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error' when calling 'tnsping' command from /etc/init.d script . The 'tnsping' command works normally without any issues.

Comment: What is your init script doing? Are you setting up the Oracle environment properly? Which rc level does it run at - are you sure the network layers are up at the point it runs, for instance?

Comment: As Alex already mentioned, you could start by checking the Oracle environment. See if variables like $ORACLE_HOME, $ORACLE_SID, $TNS_ADMIN are defined in the scope of the shell that's running the script.